# Form database in SQL

Tags: mysql, database, forms

I am trying to setup tables in a MySQL database for one of my class projects. The project involves us submitting html forms to a database. So currently I have a table for every form that I am currently submitting the to database. I also have a user table which holds user information.

My questions is I want to link the forms tables to the user table, but I am trying to avoid having to create a linking to table from each form table to the user table separately. Is it possible to not do this?

Comment: Put the `id` of the users row in each of the forms tables as for example `user_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming each user submission is a row entry in the `Form` tables? Without the `user_id` column already in your schema, how did you differentiate which entry is which user to begin with?

For your question, it depend on what you want to output with these form tables. If all you want to do is to output the content of the forms for a given user, then adding a `user_id` column to each of your form table will suffice.

However, if a form requires some additional information about the user in the Users table, might as well add the `user_id` column as a foreign key to the `Users` table that you can join with.

I don't see what is the restriction to "linking to table", unless your have ***a lot*** of Form tables